# How to specify which chars to use to tokenize the request?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I've got a bunch of rules to tokenize the requests. Most of them are fit to `word_delimiter` filter. But I also want to specify which chars to use to tokenize the requests, e.g. `,`, `:`, `-`, `_`...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

By specifying char filter in a custom analyzer, you can :

> preprocess the string of characters before it is passed to the tokenizer. A character filter may be used to strip out HTML markup, , or to convert "&" characters to the word "and": https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/analysis-charfilters.html

The step in a custom analyzer are :

1. Character filters
2. Tokenizers
3. Token filters

according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html

A Mapping Char Filter should help you to preprocess your specified char into token which will be taken into account by the rest of your analysis process